# (Excel) Finding the column header associated with a cell, returning a list of names and headers

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm looking for a method that can find a cell's column header, based on the fact that there's an empty cell above it. Here's the context:

I want to generate a column of all names, with the header associated with them in an adjoining column.

I have lists of names, each under a header, such that

```
header 1   <blank>       header 2   <blank>
1          First Last    1          First Last
2          First Last    2          First Last
3          First Last    3          First Last
...        ...           ...        ...

header 3   <blank>       header 4   <blank>
1          First Last    1          First Last
2          First Last    2          First Last
3          First Last    3          First Last
...        ...           ...        ...
```

And I'm trying to get:

```
Names         Headers
First Last    header 1
First Last    header 1
First Last    header 1
...           ...
First Last    header 2
First Last    header 2
First Last    header 2
...           ...
First Last    header 3
First Last    header 3
First Last    header 3
...           ...
First Last    header 4
First Last    header 4
First Last    header 4
...           ...
```

It seems like I'll have to have something that crawls the spreadsheet looking for "names" and every time it finds a name, travel up the column until it encounters a blank space, and then go left one cell. Then, copy that text, and make two new columns with the name and header text. How can I start doing that?

Here is a sample algorithm

```
1   Create a new worksheet that’s a copy    
2   Find all cells with just a number; delete, move left    
3   Find cells with empty cell above. These are headers 
4   For every cell that is not a header,    
        a Find the associated header
        b Print the name and header in a new sheet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a formula and some rearranging of the data.

1. Insert new columns to the right of each of your names columns.
2. Put this formula in the cell to the right of your first name and
   fill down:

   `=IF(B2="","",IF(B1="",OFFSET(B1,0,-1),C1))`
3. Copy the formula to the cell to the right of the name that will have
   "header 2" and fill down.

This will give you the headers in the correct places:

[image]

Now you can copy the new columns and Paste Special > Values, to remove the formulas.  That will allow you to delete the old header columns.

Finally, move the right hand section below the left, and sort on the header column.

Comment: Thanks! That definitely worked! I thought there might be an if statement in the solution, but it was Offset that I never would have thought of. I would give you a vote up but I don't have enough rep on this stack exchange. Thanks!

Comment: Great.  Glad to help.